# Debug net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 errors

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, arr

On IIS server with a site behind ARR Reverse Proxy, a site works fine except sometimes I get following error:

net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)

This gives me a blank page!

[image: Screenshot of the error]

However, when I refresh the page it just load correctly.

What could be wrong? How to check what issue is?

Comment: How often can you see such? Tools like Wireshark can reveal more about the details (IIS FRT can also shed some light).

Comment: Could you share a simple demo that could reproduce your issue?

Comment: @LexLi We are not getting this issue on all requests, its intermittent.. however when you browse many pages... sometimes you get it.

Comment: @Rena We do not have a demo that can be used to reproduce.. However, Is there a way to share a URL with you personally? As I can not publish it here for some purpose.